# Jquery.noConflict issue?

Tags: jquery

I need two jQuery sources and i don't know if i am implementing .noConflict correctly?

```
<link href="count/jquery.countdown.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Count/jquery.countdown.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function () {
            var Day = new Date();
            Day = new Date(2015, 11, 22, 09, 00, 00, 00)
            $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: Day});
            $('#year').text(Day.getFullYear());
        });
        jQuery.noConflict(true);
    </script>               

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Video/css/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Video/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Video/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Video/js/flowplayer-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Video/js/jquery.fancybox-1.2.1.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Video/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Video/js/fancyplayer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var videopath = "http://www.site.co.uk/Video/";
        var swfplayer = videopath + "videos/flowplayer-3.1.1.swf";
    </script>
```

Comment: you haven't closed what you opened with `$(function () {`

Comment: Note regarding passing `true`, from the docs: *(...)we need to consider that most plug-ins rely on the presence of the jQuery variable and may not operate correctly in this situation.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Regarding your update, I think you just need to specify a parameter for your ready handler:

```
$(function($) {
    //...
});
jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

So that the code inside the handler refers to the first version and not to the second one (the second jQuery include will overwrite `$` otherwise).

---

I think if you pass `true`, which essentially also resets `jQuery`, you have to assign a reference to that jQuery version on your own:

```
var jQueryVersionX = jQuery.noConflict(true);
jQueryVersionX(function($) {
    // $ references the jQueryVersionX;
});
```

jQuery passes a reference to itself as first argument to the ready handler.

If you include both scripts in the header, then `jQuery` will first reference the second included version. After calling `jQuery.noConflict(true)`, `jQuery` will refer to the first included version.

But note from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/):

> If necessary, we can free up the `jQuery` name as well by passing `true` as an argument to the method. This is rarely necessary, and if we must do this (for example, if we need to use multiple versions of the jQuery library on the same page), **we need to consider that most plug-ins rely on the presence of the jQuery variable and may not operate correctly in this situation**.

Make sure you include the versions and the plugins in the right order.